# system.webServer/rewrite -> UrlRewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

I have a php project with this `Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But need to install it on IIS6. Wondering if its possible to configure on [UrlRewriting.NET](http://urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html)? And how?

Answer (score 0):

One of the limitations of UrlRewriting.NET is that only pages and resources handled by the ASP.NET pipeline can be rewritten, which of course PHP can't be.

You would need a third party tool such as [Iconics IRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) or [HeliconTech's ISAPI_Rewrite3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) to be able to satisfy your rewrite requirements.